# Wordpress Custom taxonomy dropdown with childen and hierarchy

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu

I'm using a property theme for wordpress for my venue based project. In there ive got a search that is based on the custom taxonomies, the one i need help with is the location.

Initially i had Country and City - but after finding that i couldn't seem to populate the cities based on what the user selected for the country (AJAX i though but i cant figure out how to do it even after surfing the net for hours). I saw a post that said to make it into one taxonomy which i called Location, this now is a hierarchal taxonomy which has a cities as children

what i'm having a problem with is that for the search i've got a dropdown now which is showing the cities but not with the hierarchy!

so it look like (for example)

Brazil
Florence
Italy
Mexico
United States

where it should be showing it as

Brazil
Italy
-Florence
Mexico
United States

the dropdowns are all called like

```
<div class="left">
    <label for="ct_state"><?php _e('Location', 'contempo'); ?></label>
    <?php ct_search_form_select('country'); ?>
</div>
```

The function that is called is

```
function ct_search_form_select($name, $taxonomy_name = null) {
    global $search_values;

    if (!$taxonomy_name) {
        $taxonomy_name = $name;
    }
    ?>
    <select id="ct_<?php echo $name; ?>" name="ct_<?php echo $name; ?>">
        <option value="0"><?php _e('Any', 'contempo'); ?></option>
        <?php foreach( get_terms($taxonomy_name, 'hide_empty=0') as $t ) : ?>
            <?php if ($search_values[$name] == $t->slug) { $selected = 'selected="selected" '; } else { $selected = ''; } ?>
            <option <?php echo $selected; ?>value="<?php echo $t->slug; ?>"><?php echo $t->name; ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
    <?php
}
```

As you can see it also pulls a variable called $search_values which is how im compiling all the selections into a search query. Is there is quick fix for this anywhere? i've tried doing different functions and i just cant get anything to work :( please someone help me

thanks so much
nickey

Answer (score 0):

Got a friend to help me out on this - incase anyone else has this problem, created a new function just for those dropdowns

```
function ct_location_form_select($name, $tax_name = null, $parent = null) {
    global $search_values;

    if (!$tax_name) {
        $tax_name = $name;
    }

    $tax_array['hide_empty'] = 0;
    $tax_array['parent'] = ( $parent ) ? $parent : 0;
    $tax_terms = get_terms( $tax_name, $tax_array );

    if ($parent) {
        foreach( $tax_terms as $t ) {
            if ( $search_values[$name] == $t->slug ) { $selected = 'selected="selected"'; } else { $selected = ''; }
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $t->slug; ?>" <?php echo $selected; ?>><?php echo get_option_spaces( $tax_name, $t->term_id ) . $t->name; ?></option>
            <?php
            if ( get_term_children( $t->term_id, $tax_name ) ) {
                ct_location_form_select( $name, $tax_name, $t->term_id );
            }
        }
    } else {
    ?>
    <select id='ct_<?php echo $name; ?>' name='ct_<?php echo $name; ?>'>
    <option value="0"><?php _e('Any', 'contempo'); ?></option>
    <?php foreach( $tax_terms as $t ) { ?>
    <?php if ( $search_values[$name] == $t->slug ) { $selected = 'selected="selected" '; } else { $selected = ''; } ?>
    <option <?php echo $selected; ?>value="<?php echo $t->slug; ?>"><?php echo $t->name; ?></option>
    <?php
            if ( get_term_children( $t->term_id, $tax_name ) ) {
                ct_location_form_select( $name, $tax_name, $t->term_id );
            }
        }
    ?>
    </select>
    <?php
    }
}
```

Cheers!